# Send data in on-* event on polymer

Tags: javascript, data-binding, polymer

I'm having a little problem, I have a list where I show some information and an a delete icon for each one, something like this:

```
<template id="template" repeat="{{response}}">
                <tr>
                    <td>{{val}}</td>
                    <td>{{day}}</td>
                    <td>{{useFor}}</td>
                    <td align="right" style="padding: 0;">
                        <core-icon-button icon="icons:delete" on-click="{{showMore}}"></core-icon-button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </template>
```

I want to send the {{val}} information when the users click on the selected data, but I don't know how, I tried several things like {{showMore({{val}})}} / on-clic="{{showMore}}" data-value="{{val}} and other stuff but nothing working to me for now, did you have some way to perfmor this action?

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't but you get a target reference which is the clicked element passed with the event.

```
<core-icon-button icon="icons:delete" on-click="{{showMore}}" some-data="{{val}}"></core-icon-button>
```

and in the event handler you can read the `some-data` attribute from target, which is the bound `val`.
(I use this only know this from Dart but I'm sure you'll find a code example how the syntax has to look like exactly.)

You can also access the `templateInstance`

```
e.target.templateInstance.model.<property>
```

where `property` would be `val` according to the example above.
See http://www.polymer-project.org/resources/faq.html#templateinstancemodel for more details.

Comment: I love you man! you saved my as*/life I did the following

console.log(sender.templateInstance.model.val);